# Given an angle at a point A and given another segment BC, construct a point D so that the angle DBC equals the given angle at A.

Tags: geometry, solid-angle

I'm not sure if I understand this question right.

Q. Given an angle at a point A and given another segment BC, construct a point D so that the angle DBC equals the given angle at A.

Figure - [image: Question Figure]

Should I assume one of the sides of the angle a is bc and the end point of the other side is the point d ?

Comment: Not quite. One of the sides of the *reproduced angle* is $bc$, and the endpoint of the other side is $d$.

Comment: @DavidMitra - I might be misinterpreting what you said, but how is that different from what I intended on assuming ?

Comment: I may be misinterpreting you. It seemed you wanted to take angle $a$ and just call one of its sides $bc$. You have to, of course, reproduce the angle on the line segment $bc$ as given. (The reproduced angle has to be called something other than "$a$").

Comment: @DavidMitra - You are right. But I am still confused on how to reproduce the angle a on the line segment bc?

Comment: Hint: 1) Draw an arc, with arbitrary radius, on angle $a$ with center the vertex of $a$. Call the points of intersection of $a$ and the arc $e$ and $d$ .  2) Draw an arc of radius $d$ with center $b$ on the segment $bc$ 3) How could you find the points on the arc drawn in 2) that correspond  to the points $d$ and $e$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David Mitra was spot on. Go the the following link it has the proof and a java video to help you understand. Are you in Math430 UMD?

http://www.mathopenref.com/constcopyangle.html